# Should this be flagged for moderator or is this acceptable?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, scope, accepted-answer

This user enters the thread one week after the question has "died" out.
And this is more or less this user's way of doing. Always enters late, and in all fairness creates good answers, then almost to the point of bullying the OP till they give him/her the green tick.

This time the user has gone to the extreme length that he not only made an answer, in the answer explains how superior it is, then comments and tags the OP, and then even edits the OPs question to give a hint that he is there and has posted an answer.
Seriously?
The point he is trying to make has been clear to OP for a week and has understood his "error".

---

**In question:**

> "Edit by [answerer]: The OP's input string is .... This is the confusion / misrepresentation in the question and why the OP struggled to receive a correct/working response from the other volunteers."

**From answer:**

> There are a few ways that you can tackle this issue:  ([Demo Link](http://example.com))
>
> The reason that all of the other answers fail is because you have misrepresented your input string.  Your actual input string contains `&lt;` which is the html entity for `<`.  My methods below will clarify this point to future SO readers and help you to select the best approach for your project.
>
> ```
> //Some code, not relevant to this question
> ```

**Comments below answer:**

> @(OP's name) Because the other answers do not use the correct input string, their answers will not work and they will only confuse future SO readers. Please award my answer the green tick so that future readers can navigate directly to a correct and clear answer. - [Answerer](http://example.com)

> @(OP's name) I have awakened to see that my correct answer that helped you has suddenly lost 17 points. Can you explain why you have stripped the green tick from my answer and given it to the answer that was deemed incorrect for your case earlier? This seems a bit rude. Furthermore my answer shows a method to extract the substring with one function call
> (`strstr`) rather than two calls or the expense of regex. My answer is worthy the green tick in every way. The new accepted answer will not make any sense for future SO readers, but mine will. I ask you to re-evaluate your decision. - [Answerer](http://example.com)

---

I have not removed any other comments here, it's only the person who owns the answer who is typing in the comments.

In short is this acceptable or should this user be flagged?

Again this is not a one-time thing from this user.
I have seen it several times and he usually removed his "begging" when OP responds to it or the comments where he explains how his answer is better.
But now I can finally see it and not just OPs responses to his deleted comments.

Comment: tl;dr:  It's fine if it's done once and not in an overly aggressive fashion.  My gut tells me that any moderator would delete this comment outright since it doesn't add anything to the post, so feel encouraged to flag.

Comment: Editing the _question_ itself to address other answerers (quote: _"Edit by [user]: The OP's input string is .... This is the confusion / misrepresentation in the question and why the OP struggled to receive a correct/working response from the other volunteers."_) is a little over the edge. A mod flag may be warranted.

Comment: @Makoto the user has been a member for almost four years and it's not a "once thing" I have seen it several times from this user.

Comment: @Andrew and the topic has been edited to suit his answer too.

Comment: Really, the solution to things like this is flagging. If you see somebody doing something that seems really wrong, mod flag it (assuming that no other flag suits the situation), and explain the situation as fully as possible in your flag description. The moderators may or may not agree with your perception. Be sure to read what they write if they decline your flag. But don't be afraid of having your flag declined. If somebody is being abusive, then that needs to be dealt with.

Comment: Also I don't find the duplicate on this thread correct. It has to do with not accepting at all. This is not the same. In this case OP has accepted but one answerer is very determined to make OP switch correct answer. Although my answer is marked correct now it was yesterday it bacame correct. And I don't find my answer more correct than any other. So it's not a case of me trying to hold on to the 15 points.

Comment: I'm not for naming and shaming, but in this instance, it would be useful to know who it actually was, so we can judge for ourselves if there's a clear pattern.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth If you really must know, the first line of the answer in the screenshot is enough to identify.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I would love to link to the post or the users profile but I believe people will start downvoting the users answers because they are always "the best/cleanest/simplest/best-performing method" and it can be annoying for some. Me including. Also as I wrote in my edit the user usually removed his begging/bad mouting of other answers as soon as OP has seen it so you will only see the last few. And maybe a few OP comments. But it seems Andrew has found the user even if I really don't want to name and shame as you say. It doesn't lead to anything.

Comment: @Andreas fair consideration. I trust meta users not to go on a downvoting spree but just let the community and moderators do their work.

Comment: @Erik lol! Yes.... I posted an link to one of my answers in another thread here on meta. I knew it wasn't a perfect answer and that was the point too. None of the answers in the thread was perfect and yet my answer was the only one to get downvoted and commented on how poor it was. After posting it on meta it became a downvote spree just as you say. No thanks, not doing that again. If we could keep meta to meta topics it would be fine. Meaning "here we have a problem let's discuss it in a grown up manner without hammering the linked thread". But that's not how it works here... :-/

Comment: @Andreas walking through his 10 most recent answers, I don't see any begging, any other inappropriate edits, or any inappropriate comments. This single edit is inappropriate in my opinion (we have accepted answers and votes to see which answer is the valid one), but I can understand why he posted it. The boasting is something I can see, but I'm not sure that warrants a mod flag. My advice: flag inappropriate comments with the usual flags (no longer needed or, if it's rude, rude or abusive), reverse inappropriate edits as you see them (I don't see a pattern), and mod flag if edits are reapplied

Comment: @Erik keep in mind that as I say, he removes comments after OP reads it. I have seen this for several months and not just the last few posts. The user has "stolen" one answer from me a few months ago and that was when it cought my eye. And all I can see in this thread is how OP responds to something the user wrote that was bad mouting my answer. And I have seen it several times after that too. And have to some point keept an eye on old threads when this user enters.

Comment: @Andreas Copying an answer without referring to it's author is plagiarism, and warrants a moderator flag. If you flag the inappropriate comments one-by-one, and if a lot of those flags get accepted, you have a strong case, but now, I can't see these comments, so I can't judge them. I agree with you that this edit was inappropriate and should be reverted.

Comment: We've handled this specific case now, thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Oh wow this went pearshaped quickly! Guys you have to keep in mind I'm not as fast as you, and I have a baby to take care of. My girlfriend calls me a sedated tortoise. I'm still thinking about IF I should flag the post. My intention was not to name and shame or to have any impact at all. I thought I masked the user but obviously that didn't work ( I could have figured that out with my toes, posting on a site full of "computer nerds"). I'm still at the start line and you all raced to the finnish line and had a shower.

Comment: @Erik sorry for the confusion, he did not copy my answer. I meant as I wrote an answer that the OP accepted and "some time" passed and this person wrote an answer. Then the begging and pleading started. There is one comment removed from this user where he explains how his answer is better than mine. I haven't seen it but it's obvious by looking at OPs comments. Sorry for the confusion. I hope this is not the reason it all went the direction it did. That was not my intention.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Leaving comments to inform new users in how to accept questions [is okay the first time](/a/251298/5764553).

Leaving comments to explain problems with answers is okay. (That's part of the reason comments are there.)

Badgering the OP and telling them to switch the accept back to your own answer is a little sketchy. That would usually warrant a "No longer needed" flag. In this particular case, the comment has further explanation, so the "No longer needed" flag would probably be declined (the flag could only be accepted by deleting the comment, and if the comment has useful content, the moderator wouldn't delete it.) A mod-flag would probably be good.

*Editing the question* to address other answers and tell everybody that they misunderstood the problem is not good. That is a bad edit and should be reverted. That text should be in a comment, not the question.

---

There are [guidelines about being nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), but not many hard laws. In general, **if you think somebody is crossing the line somewhere, mod-flag them and see what the moderators think.** Moderators are pretty level-headed, and may know something more about the user. If they decline your flag, be sure to read what they say, but don't let the fear of getting declined keep you from flagging. If there really is a problem, then that should be dealt with.

If this user has a history of edgy/confrontational posts, be sure to mention (and link) to these posts in your flag description. It makes things a lot easier for moderators if you give details.

Comment: I'll see if I can find some old posts of his begging but most of it is deleted since the user does that once OP responds. But since you have found the user, see the latest answer. Same thing as I posted here.